# Should I change the article for a noun starting with a vowel sound if it is preceeded but an adjective starting with a consonant sound and vice versa?

Tags: grammar, articles

For example, when I say:

"This is a conversation about hats."

Should I say...

"This is an off-the-cuff conversation about hats?"

..With the preceding adjective off-the-cuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely do it. It's not about parts of speech (nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc). It's about words. Here's a simpler example:

It's a city. (c is a consonant sound)

It's an old city. (o is a vowel sound)

It's a very old city. (v is a consonant sound)

Comment: It's totally about the sound.

Comment: But it is also about the parts of the speech because there would be no article without there being a noun in the sentence right? So the noun determines if there is an article in a sentence and the word that goes before the noun, and the sound that it starts with, determines if we should use the definite or indefinite article. Correct me if I'm wrong.